Why is a sum of alternatively flipped and offset gaussians equal to cosine?
Through inspection, the following appears to be true:
$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n e^{-(x-n)^2} = k\cos(\pi x)$$
where $k\approx3$. Even the case for $n=2$ appears to be a very good approximation for $x\in[-0.5, 0.5]$. However, I can't think of any reason why this would be true. Is this equality actually true and, if so, why?

I think the Poisson summation formula will be useful here. My guess is that you'll get another summation, except with more rapidly decaying terms, so the first term by itself will be a good approximation.

Let $f_x(t) = \exp\left[i\pi(t-x)-(t-x)^2\right]$. Note that $f_0(t) = \exp(i\pi t - t^2)$ has Fourier transform $$\widehat{f}_0(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_0(t)e^{-i2\pi t\omega}\,dt = \sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-\pi^2\left(\omega-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right].$$
Hence, the shifted version $f_x(t) = f_0(t-x)$ has Fourier transform $$\widehat{f}_x(\omega) = e^{-i2\pi x\omega}\widehat{f}_0(\omega) = \sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x\omega -\pi^2\left(\omega-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right].$$
Then, the Poisson summation formula gives us $$\begin{align*}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}f_x(n) &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}_x(k) 
\\
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[i\pi(n-x)-(n-x)^2\right] &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi xk -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\\
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[i\pi n -(n-x)^2\right] &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[i\pi x -i2\pi xk -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\\
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{-(x-n)^2} &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\end{align*}$$
where we multiplied both sides by $\exp(i\pi x)$ and simplified things.
Now, if we split the right side into the ranges $k = -\infty, \ldots, 0$ and $k = 1,\ldots,\infty$, make the substitution $k' = 1-k$ into the first sum and then combine things, we get
$$\begin{align*}&\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\\
= &\sum_{k = -\infty}^{0}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right] + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\\
= &\sum_{k' = 1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[i2\pi x(k'-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k'-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right] + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left[-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}) -\pi^2\left(k-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2\right]
\\
= &\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sqrt{\pi}\left[\exp\left(i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2})\right) + \exp\left(-i2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2})\right)\right]\exp\left(-\pi^2(k-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 \right)
\\
=& \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}2\sqrt{\pi}\cos(2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2}))\exp\left(-\pi^2(k-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 \right)
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, we have $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{-(x-n)^2} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}2\sqrt{\pi}\exp\left(-\pi^2(k-\tfrac{1}{2})^2 \right)\cos(2\pi x(k-\tfrac{1}{2})).$$
Now, it's not hard to see that the $k = 1$ term is $2\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi^2/4}\cos(\pi x)$, and the $k = 2$ term is $2\sqrt{\pi}e^{-9\pi^2/4}\cos(3\pi x)$, etc. Notice that $2\sqrt{\pi}e^{-9\pi^2/4} \approx 8 \times 10^{-10}$, and the terms for $k \ge 3$ are even smaller. Hence, the sum is approximately $2\sqrt{\pi}e^{-\pi^2/4}\cos(\pi x)$.
